# Indoor navigation Beacons

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, estimote

I want to develop application for indoor navigation.

[Estimote](http://estimote.com/?gclid=CK63tuPnkdMCFQoeaAodL_IMzg) do not provides indoor navigation for Android. They provide for iOS as of now.

My requirement is :

1. I want to find nearest beacon.
2. Draw map for all beacons near by like google map for region.
3. I want exact view like Google map navigation for direction like user is walking within shopping mall so direction arrow should follow the same.

Any one can help???

I need suggestion/code example for the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any one help me??

Comment: i think you should first search through stackoverflow for beacon estimote, before asking a solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are several companies, who provide solution for indoor positioning using iBeacon.

As far as I know, https://navigine.com, https://indoo.rs, http://indooratlas.com do exactly you want.
You can draw map, add barriers, beacons, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

To meet all of your requirements, you need to create a detailed map for your indoor location with correct dimensions, with all doors, stairs etc.

Also you need to "connect" location of your beacons with this map. Besides Estimote, there are some other companies that has [Android](https://github.com/leantegra/AndroidWiBeatSDK) and [iOS](https://github.com/leantegra/iOSWiBeatSDK) SDKs with such functionality.